# Android 10: How to detect if the user accepted/rejected the permission CHANGE_WIFI_STATE from the Android system notification?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, android-wifi, android-10.0

I'm using `addNetworkSuggestions` on Android 10 to auto connect to an existing Wifi access point using [this doc reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-suggest).

I'm using the following code :

```kotlin
val wifiManager = context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE) as WifiManager;

val status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);
if (status != WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
    // do error handling here
}

// Optional (Wait for post connection broadcast to one of your suggestions)val intentFilter = IntentFilter(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);

val broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        if (!intent.action.equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
            return;
        }
        // do post connect processing here
    }
};
context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
```

I'm using an Android 10 device and I'm getting a notification inviting the user to allow or not the permission:

[image: Android permission notification]

According to the doc, this is the correct behaviour on Android 10:

> On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, the user sees a dialog if the app is running in the foreground, and a notification if the app is running in the background.

> On Android 10 (API level 29), the user sees a notification, regardless of whether the app is running in the foreground or the background.

If the permission is not yet accepted, I want to show some text inviting the user to accept the permission notification. But if the user has already accepted the permission notification, I would hide this text.

The question is: How to detect if the user accepted/rejected the permission in the Android system notification ?

I've tried the following:

- I've checked the result of `wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions` method but it returns `STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS` even though the permission was not granted yet.

```kotlin
val status = wifiManager.addNetworkSuggestions(suggestionsList);
if (status != WifiManager.STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS) {
    // this is not triggered even though the user didn't accept the permission notification
}
```

- `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission`

```kotlin
ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE)
```

But it always returns `true`

- `AppOpsManager.unsafeCheckOp`

From [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/224071894):

```kotlin
appOpsManager.unsafeCheckOp("android:change_wifi_state", Process.myUid(), applicationContext.packageName) == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
```

It returns `true` even if the permission was not yet accepted/rejected. But it returns `false` when the user has rejected the permission.
This works only for the case when the user has refused the Android permission notification.

- From Desmond's suggestions I've tried using `requestPermissions` on `Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE`. I correctly receive the `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` value. But I keep getting the notification permission.

---

I have the following permissions in the manifest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Comment: I honestly don't think Android "keeps" track of that state you need *until the user is prompted*. An alternative would be for YOU to keep track internally when you've asked, that way you know that if the method returns false, the user rejected it. Didn't you also get a boolean as well indicating when the user rejected *and said "don't ask again"* or something like that? It's been a while.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini Thank you for your response, I've edited the question in regard to your indication. The method `addNetworkSuggestions` returns `STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS` (0) even though the permission is not granted (eg the user didn't accept the permission from the Android notification). Storing a boolean won't work because we don't know if the user has accepted or not the permission from the Android notification. The only thing we do know is if the user rejected the permission using `appOpsManager.unsafeCheckOp("android:change_wifi_state",....)`.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I'm looking for a way to findout if the user has not accepted yet the permission (eg the user has not seen the notification or has not accepted yet)

Comment: @BertrandMartel any luck to this problem? I am also having same problem. In addition, It returns 0 i.e. STATUS_NETWORK_SUGGESTIONS_SUCCESS but, doesn't show suggestions to the user on notification bar(Android 10)